# Building Hybrid network on Azure is it possible?

Tags: azure, server, cloud, windows-server-2008, azure-storage

I need to build a hybrid Azure cloud network moreover it will be used as a failover network. I will tell you the scenerio let me know is it possible.
I have 5 sites lets name it A, B,C,D and E. Site A is the main site and it has Primary Domain Controller Server , DNS Server.
Site B and Site C has only Domain controller.
Site D and E have no servers at their location and they are dependent on Site A for AD authentication.
Every site has ReadyNAS which uses AD authentication.
So now the situation is if Site A goes down completely then the Site B and C can communicate with their local NAS drives as they have Domain Controller in house and it provides AD authentication. But site D and E are unable to it because they are dependent on Site A so to remove this dependency I thought of building a failover network on Azure such that I will have one DC server on Azure which is in sync with DC servers on site though VPN and if the site A goes down the site D and E still get authenticated from DC on Azure and they could access their local NAS drives. I just wanted to know is it possible in real life and what configuration changes on AD sites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could deploy an Hybrid Site-to-Site VPN with Azure. For this you will be needing some supported VPN Devices such as the ones included in the supported VPN devices list: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices/ , you should look for route-based supported devices that will let you add different "branch offices or sites" to the Azure VPN. Those devices need to be able to open tunnel connections using IKEv2 protocol and have an assigned public IP address.

You will probably need to set up one VPN Site to Site connection from site A, B or C to replicate a secondary domain controller in Azure.

And then you should set up VPN site to site connections from site E and D. Both sites should be able to see the Secondary domain controller in Azure, you need to be sure to check the DNS for the local machines in sites E and D so that they can be routed to Azure Secondary DC. You need to be aware that depending on your actual networking equipment in sites A, B, or C and in site E and D, you might need to upgrade or purchase new hardware that supports IKEv2 protocols.

For setting up Site to Site connections and creating a VNET in azure you should look into this documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal/